# Get the full @ObjectName in a custom SSMS report?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssms

I'm trying to create a custom report for a **table column** node in Sql Server Management Studio (v17.9.1), but the *@ObjectName* parameter doesn't include the table name, making that whole feature useless. The same applies to SP and FN parameters, which is equally stupid.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/object/use-custom-reports-with-object-explorer-node-properties?view=sql-server-ver15) doesn't mention anything about it, and none of the official parameters contain table/parent object information.

Am I missing something here? Is there some undocumented parameter or trick I can use to get hold of the parent table it belongs to? Did nobody actually think about this?